# Centering with CSS

Tags: css, center

I want to set my drop down menu in the middle of my page. I could make it both left aligned or centered, but now it is not working anymore.

```
#navigation {
    margin-top: -50;
    background: #000;
    height: 3em;
    list-style: none;
    position: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: +1;
}

#navigation > li {
    position: relative;
    left:15%;
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1cm 0 1cm;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navigation > li > a {
    position: relative;
    left:15%;
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    color: #c60;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 3;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navigation > li > a:hover {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation > li.sub {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul {
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #a40;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    display: inline;
    top: -1000em;
    z-index: +2;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 0.3em auto;
    display: inline;
    z-index: +2;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li a {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #c60;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation > li.sub:hover ul {
    top: 3em;
    z-index: +2;
}
```

This code used to make the menu centered but it's not working anymore.

Comment: You need to post your HTML too. CSS without HTML is of no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a snippet of the HTML code for your navigation dropdown, I went ahead and did some detective work to figure it out. So given that the HTML structure is something like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="sub">
        <a>option</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>sub-option</a></li>
            <li><a>sub-option</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub">
        <a>option</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>sub-option</a></li>
            <li><a>sub-option</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>lonely option</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I noticed that there were a few problems in your CSS, I've added comments below to discuss these. So this is your current CSS:

```
#navigation {
    margin-top: -50;     /* <-- missing measurement unit, px? em? */
    background: #000;
    height: 3em;
    list-style: none;
    position: center;    /* <-- no such thing as 'center' */
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: +1;         /* <-- not a big deal but you can leave out the plus for positive integers. */
}

#navigation > li {
    position: relative;
    left:15%;            /* <-- this one ... */
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1cm 0 1cm;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navigation > li > a {
    position: relative;
    left:15%;            /* <-- ... and this were the ones causing you grief */
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    color: #c60;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 3;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navigation > li > a:hover {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation > li.sub {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul {
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #a40;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    display: inline;
    top: -1000em;
    z-index: +2;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 0.3em auto;
    display: inline;
    z-index: +2;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li a {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation > li.sub ul li a:hover {
    background: #c60;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation > li.sub:hover ul {
    top: 3em;
    z-index: +2;
}
```

This is the [current state of the navigation dropdown](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYZmmM). Before I could solve your issue, I had to fix the following problems:

- Removed the rule `position: center;` from `#navigation {}` as it is
  not a valid rule and wasn't doing anything
- Removed the rule `left: 15%` from `#navigation > li {}` and `#navigation > li > a`. Using these two rules to try and center was not only not truly centering the dropdown but causing it to break as well.
- Removed the rule `margin-top: -50;` as it was not doing anything
- Changed `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;` in `#navigation > li {}`. This way `height: 100%;` would make the height of the `li` element the same height as the navigation bar.

Now with all that out of the way - all you need to do is, instead of using `position: center` you need to use `text-align: center` in `#navigation {}`. That will center your navigation.

Finally, here is the [updated and working navigation dropdown](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByvRdP) demo and code.